# Gradle project including a maven project as a subproject

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gradle, integration

I have a gradle project(uwantsoft-toolkit) and a maven project(test_pom).
I want to include the maven project as a subproject into the gradle project,is it possible?

I have tried this like normally including a gradle project:
In the gradle settings.gradle file add:
   rootProject.name = 'uwantsoft-toolkit'
   includeFlat 'test_pom'
When I try to add following code in the build.gradle file:
   dependencies {
      compile project(path:":test_maven",configuration:"default")
   }

An error happened:
   "Error:Module version com.uwantsoft:uwantsoft-toolkit:1.0, configuration 'compile' declares a dependency on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the module descriptor for uwantsoft-toolkit:testpom:unspecified"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Gradle project can only declare a project dependency on another Gradle project. If you have a Maven project that you want to declare as a dependency you'll have to declare it as an external module dependency. See the [Gradle documentation](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies) for more information on what types of dependencies Gradle supports.

Comment: Thanks.And in fact, I am confused about module dependencies in the build.gradle file that when the "test_maven" project included into the "uwantsoft-toolkit" project declared in the settings.gradle file. I can call the class of "test_maven"  in the "uwantsoft-toolkit", does that mean integration successfully? Why still need to add external module complie, for example "compile group: 'com.uwantsoft', name: 'testpom', version: '1.0"

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround for this, which at least works fine for development of both gradle and maven projects along.

The setup that I have to make it work:

1. Open a gradle project in IntelliJ Idea
2. Add dependency to its build.gradle, say `compile('com.test:cool-lib:0.0.1')`
3. Add according (`com.test:cool-lib:0.0.1`) maven project to maven integration panel, it will be added as a module (same level as gradle project in project view)
4. Edit run configuration of a gradle project and add before launch action  "Run maven goal". This should point to maven project working directory and the goal should be `install`

This way, you can edit both gradle and maven projects sources in the same Idea project, and maven dependency is rebuilt and installed to local repository every time you run your gradle application.